# counter-increment in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to get an ordered list first item shouldn't start with number. The number should start from second item.

please check this URL what I am trying to achieve-- http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/tXtQF/5/

here using counter-reset and counter-increment first item shows 0 and second item starts from 1.. and if anyhow I could remove a 0 my problem will solve.

Does anyone have a better idea on this?

Regards,
Kheema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change last css rule into

```
ol li:before {content: ""; color: green; display: inline-block; width: ... ; }
ol li + li:before {content: counter(chapter) "."; }
```

in this way you insert the content starting from second `li` element (I used `li + li` so it can  work also with `IE8`)

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WwNqN/

Comment: okay agree it will work, but what about the alignment.. once the number removed, its not aligned anymore with otherones..

Comment: Hi there, do you have any idea about @counter-style trinary in CSS

Comment: what do you exactly mean? is this question strictly related to your code? If not, you should accept one answer and open a new question

Comment: I am not asking another question, just curious instead of using counter property can we use @counter-style in CSS. check this link where I found this URL .http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-lists/#counter

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this rule:

```
ol li:nth-of-type(1):before{content: "";}
```

This will remove the zero at the first element.