# Line Numbers every nth Line with CSS Counters?

Tags: css

I had to cut out certain referring links (italicized) as I don't have enough reputation yet, but can perhaps replace them later.

I've created a jQuery plug-in that displays incremented line numbers for poetry and drama; The lines of a poem are represented as the children of an ordered list (ol.verse). When javascript is enabled, the plug-in generates line numbers every nth interval based on a minimum of inline list values. These numbers can then be manipulated through the DOM. When JS is disabled, numeric list markers every fifth line kick in as fallback line numbers.

I wonder now whether it is possible to get the plugged poem to degrade as a list powered by CSS Counters. IE 6-7 get served plain ordered lists with the trailing periods of the numerals, but superior browsers should get counters or the numbers generated by the plugin. Here's the catch. The CSS counter rules should be able to accommodate situations where *the line numbering and the child-indexing of the poem list do not sync*. I've seen a number of posts on *formatting counters* and [skipping children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186849/counter-increment-in-css), as well as *the right and wrong ways of formatting poems semantically and [typographically](http://webtypography.net/intro/)* (the *[W3C proposals](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/PoeticSemantics#How_to_Markup_a_Stanza_or_Strophe.3F)* recommending paragraph and pre tags are questionable at best); I have come up empty, however, on the problem of using counters to do incremented line numbers, so I am sharing my own efforts towards a solution and hope you guys can help me towards a better one.

The base rules I've been experimenting with limited success:

```css
ol.verse { counter-reset: line 0;
ol.verse li {
   display: block;       
}

ol.verse li:before {
   counter-increment: line;
   content: counter(line) " ";
}

/* hide lines, or more precisely, children, that are not a multiple of 5 */

ol.verse li:not(:nth-child(5n)):before {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

As you can see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqnguyen/qpsGv/1/), these rules display numbers every 5th line SO LONG AS every list child is to be counted as a line of the poem and SO LONG AS the passage begins from line 1, 6, 11, 16, etc. (i.e. the counter-reset is 0 or a multiple of 5). That last rule may be of interest to those wanting to do incremented line numbers for some simpler task (a simple poem for a blog entry, e.g.), but these conditions are too restrictive for our needs (a TEI-structured repository of critical editions of poetry/drama online).

**Problem 1:** When I have several excerpts or divisions of one or more works whose counter-resets are non-multiples of the default increment, I have to reference the excerpts by id and offset the hiding rule for each id'd ol.verse by the remainder. For example, an excerpt beginning from line 43 requires adjusting the counter-reset to 42, and adjusting the nth-child parameter of the hiding rule to 5n+3 (since 42 % 5 = 3). Suddenly, counters become less appealing than numbering list values by hand. This at least is better than....

**Problem 2:** Getting the browser to uncount certain lines such as subheadings or stage directions that may be embedded within the poem. To these lines, I've tried attaching a nocount class and turning off the display property or the visibility property, e.g.

```css
ol.verse li.nocount:before {
   display: none;     
}
```

OR

```css
ol.verse li.nocount:before {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

In combination with the rule hiding lines that are non-multiples of the increment, neither gives the desired results. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqnguyen/qpsGv/2/). The first triggers incorrect line numbering on the right numbers; the latter, correct numbering on the wrong ones. Is there any way to write CSS counter rules that would work whether or not the automated line numbers correspond with the correct child indexes? Perhaps there's some other combination of CSS selectors that will do the job?

Answer (score 2):

Fixing the counting is not a problem as you can use `counter-increment: line 0;` for rules you want to be excluded (*if they apply on the same element as the +1 increment*) with a higher specificity or `!important`.

(if like in your case where you apply the rule to the `:before` pseudo-element, but want to exclude based on the `li` you can apply a `counter-increment:line -1;`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qpsGv/3/

---

To display it on the right line though that is another issue as that has to do with the `nth-child` selector which does not allow for modifications... (*if it finds a child it gets counted for its purposes..*)

---

**Update**

I do not know what flexibility you have which changing the actual html, but the only solution i can see is to wrap the elements you want to not be counted in another element.

That way you can use the `nth-of-type` instead of the `nth-child`, so that you can indeed show only on multiples of 5.

In order to keep the html valid, you would need to use the `menu` element as that is the only one that allows both `li` and `ol` as children.. (*you could ofcourse use entirely different elements .. just make sure that the counting elements are different that the non-counting ones*)

So just counting on

```
menu.verse > li { counter-increment: line 1;}
```

and displaying on

```
menu.verse > li:nth-of-type(5n):before {
    content: counter(line);
    width: 2em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2em;  
}
```

when the html is

```
<menu class="verse">
 <li>countable</li>
 <ol><li>non countable</li></ol>
 <li> countable</li>
</menu>
```

should work.. (*the `<ol><li>` could just become a `div` with appropriate styling..*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qpsGv/7/

Comment: An alternative to decrementing the counter is to use `display: none` instead, which causes the counter to skip the element as the counter isn't generated at all.

Comment: @BoltClock, indeed but the OP (the code in the fiddle) applies the `.nocount` class on elements that should appear on the page.. that is why i suggested the 0 increment that overrides the previous one..

Comment: Gaby, I'd like the numbering to come out 5, 10, 15 for lines that are part of the poem. Paratext such as subheadings or stage directions (in blue on my fiddle) should not be considered as numbered lines of the poem or play. BoltClock, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Oops, I meant `display: none` on the line number itself (the rule that's commented out in the original fiddle). http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/qpsGv/5 To be clear, it does not solve the problem of line numbers being added to the wrong lines; it's just an alternative to a negative increment.

Comment: And double oops: I just noticed the OP already mentions this in the last paragraph (though my comment does offer an explanation as to why it works that way).

Comment: Yes, `:nth-of-type()` with a different set of elements is the only viable alternative that we have, so long as we don't yet have either poetry markup in HTML or the `:nth-match()` selector in CSS.

Comment: Ok, that's progress, Gaby, but I don't know about the semantics. Instead of menu, can you wrap everything in a div. Counters don't require an parent/child relation, only a hierarchy defined through the counters. I haven't played around with nth-of-type, but will try it out. Is it possible to make nth-of-type to work when the ol is inside the li rather than the way you have it?

Comment: @jeffclef, nope. That is because `nth-of-type` only takes into consideration the type of the elements (*the `li` in this case*) under the same parent.. Counters are easy because they occur in the selector you want (*and there is a great variety of selectors..*), but `nth-...` only apply to elements under the same parent.. (`child` to all, `of-type` to a specific tag)

Comment: The ***important*** thing is to have a different element (tag) for the non-countable at the same level as the countable ones..

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2, if the `class="fallback"` in your fiddle is there to stay, and not just part of the explanation of the problem, you can use that as the solution: dispense with the nth-child(5n) and use the fallback as an indicator if the line count should show or not.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpsGv/4/).
I inserted a line in there that's not part of the poem, to see if it works, and it does: you can remove the line and the rest will remain synchronised.

Comment: Yes, that could mean the OP wants it to be there temporarily until a solution has been found that doesn't require it. Mine is not such a solution.

Comment: The fallback class is meant for browsers that don't support counters and that have javascript disabled (IE6-7). In this case, the list-style-type: decimal and display: list-item properties are activated through conditional stylesheet for list items with the fallback class.