# How to prevent my text inside my <TD> part of the table from wrapping (shifting) when browser zooms in/out?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table where I want to display the paragraph exactly as it is, whether the browser zooms in or not. For example, in the image below:

[image]

The last line of the first paragraph should always end with *"suddenly she was going back with this guy."* and the last line of the second paragraph should just consist of that final one word, *"back."*. I want it to stay this way because I want to later add a column to the left that consists of line numbers.

What happens now is that when I do a Web browser (Google Chrome) zoom in or zoom out, the words tend to shift and wrap over to the next line, thus destroying the constant state of the paragraphs.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>  

<td width="422px">
<p style="text-align: justify; font-size: medium; font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura;">My biking beginnings can be summed up in two words: teenage love. My first girlfriend was small with mousy blonde hair and I was mad about her. Our romance came to an abrupt end however, when she started going out with another guy in my hometown, Crieff. He rode a 50 cc road bike first and then a 125. And whereas I had always walked my girlfriend home, suddenly she was going back with this guy.</p>

<p style="text-align: justify; font-size: medium; font-family: 'Century Gothic',futura;">I was nearly sixteen by then and already heartbroken. Then one day, on the way back from a shopping trip to Perth with my mum, we passed Buchan's, the local bike shop. I urged my mother to stop the car. I got out, walked up the short hill to the shop and pressed my nose to the window. There was a light blue 50cc bike on display right at the front of the shop. I didn't know what make it was, or if it was any good. Such trivialities were irrelevant to me. All I knew was that I could get it in three or four months time when I was sixteen and allowed to ride it. Maybe I could even get my girlfriend back.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: pre` style for paragraph, but your text should be divided into lines. Now you have each paragraph in single line.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/LD3uC/1/

Comment: Hi Lolo. Thanks for sharing this. However, with your code, the entire contents of the first paragraph extends beyond the left side of my browser in several single lines. What I need is a single justified paragraph that I can later label each line with a line number value. The line numbers will be a left-side column.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what do you mean by "the entire contents of the first paragraph extends beyond the left side of my browser in several single lines". You can numerate that if you want (example: http://jsfiddle.net/LD3uC/3/). Anyway if you created table only for line-numbering purpose, maybe you should change your design and try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856070/line-numbers-every-nth-line-with-css-counters ?

Comment: Many thanks Lolo. Not quite what I expected, but I sure did learn a thing or two from your code! It was very interesting. What I should have typed was "the entire contents of the first paragraph extends beyond the *RIGHT* side of my browser in several single lines". I made a mistake of mistaking right for left. Many thanks for your time and effort in entertaining my question. All the best!