# How can I add line numbering to my paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add line numbers in my paragraph, like shown on the screenshot, but I don't know how. What should I use? CSS or Javascript? Thank you!

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line Numbers every nth Line with CSS Counters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856070/line-numbers-every-nth-line-with-css-counters)

Comment: Actually in the duplicate you have to manually put the line numbers ...

Comment: Are your line-breaks fixed or automatically line-breaks added by the browser? In the later case you have to know, that the line numbers could be different depending on the browser!

Comment: Break lines are manualy added. I don't want to display number in every row, just in some rows.

Comment: Do you want to display line numbers manually or by auto calculation?

Comment: By auto calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom counter and use `counter-increment: custom-counter+5` so it will increment by 5 but it will start from 5 not from 1, but you can add number 1 for first `p` with `:before` and exclude it from counter.

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  counter-reset: custom-counter;
}
p {
  display: table;
}
p:not(:first-child):before {
  counter-increment: custom-counter+5;
  content: counter(custom-counter)". ";
  display: table-cell;
  color: #aaa;
}
p:first-child:before {
  display: table-cell;
  color: #aaa;
  content: '1. '
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium, blanditiis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, eligendi.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, minus.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, repellendus?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, laboriosam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hvala na odgovoru :)

Comment: But then when there are different rows here, the code won't work, just like the above, the line number does not match at all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 counters to achieve it. Assuming your sections are paragraphs:

```
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

p::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section);
}
```

See the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp).

Comment: No, he only wants to display some line numbers, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you do not want to pre-separate the lines, i.e. you let the browser automatically add the line-breaks.

You could add a second column / div next to your paragraph and fill it with line numbers. Be sure to use the same line-height so it does not get misaligned.

On the other hand you could base on @LGSon's solution and the [lining.js](http://zencode.in/lining.js/) library to access single lines.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to calculate line numbers automatically and then add just some of them?

Comment: You could make a `for` loop in javascript that brings `1<br/><br/><br/><br/>5<br/><br/><br/><br/>10` - the question is how long to go ...