# html css styled ordered list with letters digits and numbers?

Tags: html, css

We have an ordered list

```
<ol>
    <li>something good</li>
    <li>even better</li>
    <li>possibly the best</li>    
</ol>
```

Normally it would display as:

1. something good
2. even better
3. possibly the best

Is there any way to make it display as:

a1. something good

a2. even better

a3. possibly the best

And then the next list could be:

b1. bla bla bla

b2. a second list item

Thanks.. The general question is that I want a character and a symbol as well as a digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching through this page I could find two answers that gave me the solution.

[counter-increment in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186849/counter-increment-in-css)

[HTML list-style-type dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200249/html-list-style-type-dash)

Reusing one of the fiddles from those I created one that **suits your needs**:

http://jsfiddle.net/DDNEB/1/

For the list you need a:

```
ol {counter-reset: chapter 1; list-style: none;}
```

Which permits you create the variable. Then:

```
ol li+li {counter-increment: chapter 1; list-style: none;}
```

Will increment it for each li
And finally:

```
ol li:before {content: "a" counter(chapter) ".";}​
```

Content before will create the specified content, in this case a (change it with b or whatever) + number + .  .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer is awesome too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
.A li:before 
   {
    content: "A";
   }
.B li:before 
   {
    content: "B";
 }
```

And change your list to something like this:

```
<ol class="A">
    <li>something good</li>
    <li>even better</li>
    <li>possibly the best</li>    
</ol>
<ol class="B">
    <li>something good</li>
    <li>even better</li>
    <li>possibly the best</li>    
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, this happens to be exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I write new answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it... not quite what you want, but...

```
<ol type="a">
    <li>
        <ol type="1" start="1">
            <li>something good</li>
            <li>even better</li>
            <li>possibly the best</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol type="1" start="1">
            <li>something good</li>
            <li>even better</li>
            <li>possibly the best</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_ex

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.A ol {list-style: none; counter-reset: chapter 1;}
.A ol li+li {counter-increment: chapter 1; list-style: none;}
.A ol li:before {content: "a" counter(chapter) ". ";}


.B ol {list-style: none; counter-reset: chapter 1;}
.B ol li+li {counter-increment: chapter 1; list-style: none;}
.B ol li:before {content: "b" counter(chapter) ". ";}
```

AND Do like this:

```
<div class="A">
    <ol>
        <li>something good</li>
        <li>even better</li>
        <li>possibly the best</li>             
    <ol>
</div>
<div class="B">
    <ol>
        <li>something good</li>
        <li>even better</li>
        <li>possibly the best</li>           
    <ol>
</div>
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/DDNEB/7/)!
This works as well.